# What to do with a large bag of dried fennel seeds

Tags: herbs, bulk-cooking, driedherbs

I've come into the possession of half a kilo of dried fennel seeds. I don't generally cook with it or have any meal prep ideas that I can add it to... except maybe some sort of pasta sauce? It's too bitter to snack on by itself. What's a good recipe that I could use this in bulk? I don't want it to go to waste. Last resort I'll do a month of fennel tea :)

Comment: Because your question is seeking recipes, it's going to be closed, sorry.  I slipped in a quick answer before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fennel seed is a very strong spice, so you're just not going to find any preparation that uses a cup of it.  The best you can do is recipes that use a few tablespoons, like [Fennel Butter](https://www.sbs.com.au/food/recipes/fennel-butter) and [Tomato/Fennel Pickle](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1020761-tomato-and-fennel-seed-pickle).

However, the nice thing about its strong flavor is that it stores for years.  Vac-pack it in 100g pouches, and you should be able to keep using it ... or giving it to friends ... for a good long while.